Why can't my python project find ffmpeg even though it's installed in the Python library?
I am encountering an issue where my project cannot find ffmpeg, even though it is installed in the Python library. Here are the details:
When running the script, I get the following error message:

D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Additionally, I receive this error message when trying to prepare the dataset:



from pydub import AudioSegment
import os


# Specify the path to ffmpeg
ffmpeg_path = "D:\\Python-code\\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"
AudioSegment.ffmpeg = ffmpeg_path

def convert_flac_to_wav(flac_file, wav_file):
    sound = AudioSegment.from_file(flac_file, format="flac")
    sound.export(wav_file, format="wav")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get the current working directory
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    print(f"Current directory: {current_dir}")

    # Get the parent directory of the current working directory
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
    print(f"Root directory: {root_dir}")

    # Construct the path
    voice_wavs = os.path.join(root_dir, 'data', 'voice', 'wav')
    print(f"Voice WAVs directory: {voice_wavs}")

    # Ensure the directory exists
    if not os.path.exists(voice_wavs):
        os.makedirs(voice_wavs)
        print(f"Created directory: {voice_wavs}")
    else:
        print(f"Directory exists: {voice_wavs}")

    # Get all .flac files
    # Ensure .flac files are located in the current working directory
    flac_files = [f for f in os.listdir(current_dir) if f.endswith('.flac')]
    print(f"FLAC files found: {flac_files}")

    # Convert each .flac file
    for flac_file in flac_files:
        input_flac = os.path.join(current_dir, flac_file)
        output_wav = os.path.join(current_dir, flac_file.replace('.flac', '.wav'))
        convert_flac_to_wav(input_flac, output_wav)


Despite these steps, the project continues to report that ffmpeg cannot be found. Could someone help me identify what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?


Could someone help me identify what might be causing this issue

pydub github page suggest doing following in order to debug
import logging
l = logging.getLogger("pydub.converter")
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
# here do what you want with AudioSegment

this should reveal what is actually called.
D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)

This is not error, but warning, generally this mean some anomaly was detected but program is still able to work, whilst error does result in halt.

AudioSegment seems to be problematic in all the bad ways. If all you want to do is convert flac files to wav using ffmpeg, I suggest using the built-in subprocess module to call ffmpeg.exe. The modified code should look something like this:
import os
import subprocess

# Specify the path to ffmpeg
ffmpeg_path = r"D:\Python-code\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\bin\ffmpeg.exe"

def convert_flac_to_wav(flac_file, wav_file):
    subprocess.call([ffmpeg_path, '-i', flac_file, wav_file])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Unchanged


You can try to add the FFmpeg path to the system path temporarily:
import os

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "D:\\Python-code\\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\\bin"

Do this once when you start Python (or add the path to the system path prior to running Python if you wish to make this permanent).
Then you shouldn't need to set AudioSegment.ffmpeg (presumably that's the only issue).
Alternately you can use my ffmpeg-downloader for an easily updatable method . See this SO post.
